# CSOM GetImagePreviewUrl Parameters

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, csom, onedrive-for-business, image

I am trying to retrieve the image preview URL of documents in my OneDrive for Business. The CSOM File object has a method called `GetImagePreviewUrl` which takes three parameters:

- Width
- Height
- ClientType

My question is about `ClientType`, as this is expected to be a string. I've tried to figure it out by using the following things:

```
ctx.GetType().Namespace
ctx.GetType().Name
```

But sadly, none of those worked. Does anyone know what value I have to put there? If this method turns out not to work, are there any fast alternatives?

**Edit:**

I've found out that there is an alternative, however that doesn't suit my needs because the user logged in has to have view rights to the file, I want to get the files purely programmatically. I'll include it for anyone who has the same problem but different needs, you can find the solution [here](http://blog.beecomedigital.com/2015/07/27/generate-thumbnail-of-a-document-stored-in-sharepoint-from-its-url/).

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how to make the alternative work, even for my situation.

Sharepoint returned a `403` error because sharepoint had no idea who I was. After some research and fiddling I found out that the request you send to the preview page contains an authentication cookie. This cookie can be generated by code using this piece of code:

```
// Create an authentication cookie which we can send with the request so sharepoint knows who we are.
var authCookie = credentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(new Uri(imageUrl));
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, authCookie);
// Download the image data to a byte array
image = client.DownloadData(imageUrl);
```